# How to connect a controller to a software synth?

Tags: midi, alsa

I've built a software. I want to control it via a MIDI controller (e.g. keyboard). How do I get the MIDI data from the MIDI port to my software using e.g. ALSA? I'm using Linux.

Comment: I voted to close (sorry), as this question belongs on SuperUser. However, I just wanted to mention that you'd probably have better luck asking at linuxmusicians.com if you don't find an answer on SuperUser...

Comment: Nik: the question I *meant* to ask is a programming question: the SuperUser-appropriate answer of "use aconnect" presupposes that my program is coded as an ALSA device. However, I've found the program ttymidi which does this for me, so I don't mind if this question gets closed.

Comment: Ok, in that case you should at least answer your own question and mark that as correct for future googlers. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use asoundlib. This gives you MIDI events as structured objects rather than binary data.

Answer (score 0):

[ttymidi](http://www.varal.org/ttymidi/) will act as an ALSA device and print output or read input from a file. The intended use is that this file is a serial device, but /dev/stdout also works -- this can then be piped to the program. If you want to code the device yourself, the ttymidi code is probably simpler than say timidity, so you can use that as an example.

Comment: I had some trouble directing ttymidi to a pipe instead of a serial device. I'm not sure what caused this, but taking out all the ioctl stuff and the like, I got it working.